# Gradle is not executing multiple tasks

Tags: jenkins, gradle

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#_executing_multiple_tasks

I know gradle allows to execute multi-tasks in order.

In my case, gradle stopped when it finishes the first tasks

my command is like:
gradle taskA taskB taksC

It just skip everything after taskA.
My gradle is 4.1

Comment: Where have u hosted the jenkins? Ubuntu or widnows?

Comment: Ubuntu. does it matter?

Comment: Rose, I would need more info on this in order to answer you. There may be good chances that, your developer (if not you) have added those tasks in build scripts to avoid the extra build timings. So, I want you to check with your developers for this. you can refer this page: https://android.jlelse.eu/skip-several-tasks-in-gradle-quickly-dcd0a11c3487